# Free WinForms image editor control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, image-processing, image-editor

There are a lot of image editors in C#, but I need only the control, that encapsulates the editing and that I can place on my own host form.

Does anyone know of any such controls?

Comment: What do you understand under "edit images"?

Comment: Cropping, adding text, resizing. The same as MS Paint(or simplier), but implemented as a control (with all its toolboxes, etc.)

I understand I can do something like this by rewriting some existing open source editor, but just in case, looking for a ready control :).

Answer (score 2):

I got answer refer this

http://web.archive.org/web/20150302041833/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools

This article describes the program that allows one to draw graphic objects on a WPF window using the mouse and certain drawing tools. The program supports the following tools: rectangle, ellipse, line, pencil and text. My first DrawTools article shows how to do this using Windows Forms. In the WPF version, I implemented a number of additional features requested by previous article readers:

Text tool XML serialization Drawing overlays on a background image Printing Zoom

Most of the requirement is completed by this reference

**EDIT:** As of 08/09/2015 the linked article was removed from http://www.codeproject.com